# How does Google detect new devices for two factor authentication

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, google

When you enable two step verification for google accounts, you get sent a code by SMS to enter in addition to your username and password *the first time you log in with a new device*.

How do they detect that you're on a new device? I imagine for security it's probably a serverside generation of a device fingerprint, however surely one iPhone 5 is much like another - how can they be differentiated given the way the service works?

Comment: Thinking about it, I guess it's a cookie

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a website still detect my real MAC address even if I use different virtual machine each time I visit the website?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36583/can-a-website-still-detect-my-real-mac-address-even-if-i-use-different-virtual-m)

Answer (score 15):

It uses **cookies** (more specifically, the SMSV cookie h/t @Tomer). Use chrome in normal mode and login with 2FA. Open an incognito session* of Chrome and it will be a "new device". The only difference between the two is that the latter doesn't have any cookies (maybe it also has a different set of extensions, but it is unlikely that Google is using [browser fingerprinting*](https://panopticlick.eff.org))

In fact, I am under the impression said cookie only lasts for 30 days.

*make sure that if you have any extensions, they are ALL allowed in incognito mode, and you will see there is no "browser fingerprinting", as per @David Houde's answer.

Comment: And specifically, for 2FA it uses the _SMSV_ cookie.

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure what Google uses, but there are many ways to identify a system, none of which are 100%.

The most common would be using cookies or localstorage to hold a unique identifier.

Another common method is to store User-Agent data, among others like Resolution/Color Depth, Time Zone, Available Fonts, and even Browser Plugins. While these do a good job at adding to the fingerprint, in the event of a targetted attack, this information is more or less public (or at very best relatively easy to aquire), and easy to spoof.

There is some good information at [EFF](https://panopticlick.eff.org/static/browser-uniqueness.pdf) if you are interested in browser fingerprinting.