# Is it possible to restrict email accounts within one computer?

Tags: authentication, web-application, email, privacy

can emails(e.g gmail)can be configured to open-up only in my laptop ,my operating system is windows 8 and is it possible to restrict my gmail account to be opened up only in my computer?Usually we could check for unusual activity on the email but is it possible to 
restrict within my computer?

Note : i dont know where to link up this question (superuser,web.se),since main focus is on security i post it over here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid not. You might be able to solve your problem with something called "two factor authentication" though.

This is an option you can enable in Gmail where you will need to have your mobile phone with you whenever you log onto your mail. It is very easy to set up and highly recommended.

If this won't fix your issue, edit your question to add some detail about the specific worry you have, and we may be able to make a different suggestion.

Comment: Google's two-factor authentication recognizes individual computers.  Once you've authenticated on a computer, you will seldom be asked for a number from your phone again.  Details are here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37123/how-does-google-detect-new-devices-for-two-factor-authentication  This means you have effectively restricted Gmail to computers on which you've authenticated, so long as you keep control of your phone.

Comment: That's optional, if you don't tell Google to stop asking for tokens on that computer they won't.

Comment: You are right.  You declare a computer to be "trusted."  I've forgotten how.

Comment: It's a checkbox the first time you enter the authentication code. You can turn the requirement for a code back on later at https://accounts.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing possible till day. as Graham Hill said that you can use two layer authentication, mean when u login a code will be sent to you on mobile and than you have to enter that code and than you can see the inbox.

Well apart from this Gmail is continuously capturing the location from where u loggged in. And benefit of this is if someone have got your password even that he will not be able to login. Google will deny the Hacker to login as the location is changed. But there is still an option that Hacker is living beside you. Mean your account is compromised by someone close to you. in that case Gmail cannot do anything.

Another scenario is users are infected with some remote administration tools commonly known as RAT. Even than you have no solution.

**Conclusion**
Hackers are looking for human errors. Systems are Secure by nature. You need to be more cautious and more aware and keep your apps updated.