# How the whatismyip knows real ip address?

Tags: proxy, ip, http-proxy

I just realize that [this](http://www.whatismyip.com/) website knows the real ip address even if you use proxy ,i found [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36420/how-can-a-website-find-my-real-ip-address-while-im-behind-a-proxy) question, so start to test every possible way,first, this website don't have a X-Forwarded-For or X-Client-IP in its source code,second, this site don't just tell you are using proxy,it show your real ip address which it is not something that HTTP-header can tell.so how this website actually knows our ip address? is it some kind of trace back even if i disabled track data on Firefox even if we disable javascript! it shows real ip address!!

Comment: "source code"? what do you mean by that? Client side javascript? I guess the website does the recognition server-side. And the headers *do* tell the real ip address.

Comment: I guess he was reading the rendered html-source of the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WhatIsMyIP does not need anything javascript-related to get your IP. Almost always your proxy will set the header `X-Forwarded-For` on your request.  WhatIsMyIP will get your primary IP from that.

Try accessing [this site](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/browser-header-checker.html#your) and see all the headers your browser sent and the headers your proxy added. If you install Firebug on Firefox, you can compare the headers sent by the browser with the headers shown on that site.

You can turn off javascript, disable Flash, Java applets, disable tracking, and it will keep getting your IP, as it depends on your proxy, not your browser.